# Using union in codeigniter query builder, and filter in a virtual mysql column

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord, query-builder

In my project I am using datatables plugin with serverside processing. It works fine untill i do a search or order(sort) operation because it needs active record to do that.

My scenario is, i have an account table, revenue table and payment table, and I want to view all the data of revenue and payment table, thats why I need a union. my query is like below---

```
SELECT 'Income' as source, fld_type, fld_amount, ta.fld_account as account,  fld_date, tbl_revenue.fld_description as fld_traninfo, tbl_revenue.fld_created as created
        FROM tbl_revenue JOIN tbl_accounts as ta on tbl_revenue.fld_account_id = ta.fld_id
UNION
SELECT 'Expense' as source, fld_type, fld_amount, tae.fld_account, fld_date, tbl_payment.fld_description as fld_traninfo, tbl_payment.fld_created as created
        FROM tbl_payment JOIN tbl_accounts as tae on tbl_payment.fld_account_id = tae.fld_id
```

Is there any way to use query builder in this query?

And second question, you can see I created a virtual column named 'source', i want to filter this column using where clause with append this query like below

```
WHERE source like "%a%" limit(10,0)
```

But this returns that I don't have any column name 'source', how can I filter this column?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use `$this->db->query($SQL)` too

Comment: Yes I can, but after this i cannot add any modification to this query, like after this i want to order it, $this->db->order_by('id',asc); it wont work

Comment: end of SQL just Add `ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: It will be order from outside as per provided column name and direction asc or desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a way to do that but its a bit *hacky* because codeigniter's querybuilder adds an auto `SELECT` statement to the query if you didn't specify it by yourself

In order to get what you want, you've to split your select statements in 2 queries and add the where clause to this query

Something like that should work:

```
$strQuery1 = $this->db
    ->select('income as source, fld_type, fld_amount, ta.fld_account as account,  fld_date, tbl_revenue.fld_description as fld_traninfo, tbl_revenue.fld_created as created')
    ->from('tbl_revenue')
    ->join('tbl_accounts as ta', 'tbl_revenue.fld_account_id = ta.fld_id')
    ->get_compiled_select();

$strQuery2 = $this->db
    ->select('Expense as source, fld_type, fld_amount, ta.fld_account as account,  fld_date, tbl_revenue.fld_description as fld_traninfo, tbl_revenue.fld_created as created')
    ->from('tbl_payment')
    ->join('tbl_accounts as ta', 'tbl_revenue.fld_account_id = ta.fld_id')
    ->get_compiled_select();

$strWhere = substr($this->db->like('source', 'a', 'both')->get_compiled_select(), 8);

$query = $this->db->query($strQuery1.' UNION '.$strQuery2.$strWhere);
```

Comment: what is the meaning of 8 at strWhere?

Comment: as i said in my answer the where clause would look like `SELECT * WHERE source LIKE '%a%' ESCAPE '!'` so it removes the `SELECT *` part because the querybuilder adds the `select` statement per default

Comment: did it help you ?

Comment: how can i order this table? and , source is not a column in fld_list

Comment: what do you mean with `source` is not a column, this query does exact what you described in your question - and the order by part isn't that hard - just add an `order_by` after the `like` function - something like `$this->db->like('source', 'a', 'both')->order_by('your_field', 'ASC')->get_compiled_select()` should work

Comment: yeah hope that works fine, thank you so much for your kind help,